# Cannot use java value as parameter to java annotation on scala function

Tags: scala, annotations, cross-language

I have 3 java files: HW.java, myAnn.java, and Constants.java in package myApp.

Constants.java:

```
public final class Constants {
    public static final String WORLD ="World";
}
```

myAnn.java:

```
public @interface myAnn {
    java.lang.String name() default "";
}
```

HW.java:

```
class HW {
    @myAnn(name = Constants.WORLD)
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hi "+ Constants.WORLD);
    }
}
```

My app compiles and runs fine as shown above, but I want to migrate HW.java to scala as
HelloWorld.scala:

```
object HelloWorld {
  @myAnn(name = Constants.WORLD)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello " + Constants.WORLD)
  }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get

> error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found:
>   Constants.WORLD @myAnn(name = Constants.WORLD)

If I remove the annotation then HelloWorld compiles and executes as expected.

Why can I use Constants.WORLD as a parameter to an annotation from a java program, but not from a scala program? Is there something I can modify in Constants.java to allow it to be used from either java or scala? I can't modify MyAnn.java, and I can't migrate Constants.java yet.

Comment: What Scala version are you using? I have Scala 2.9.0.1 final and everything compiles and runs just fine. Btw, it might be a good advice to compile the annotation separately from the rest of the code...

Comment: I'm using 2.8.1.final - I'll try updating.

Comment: Just tried with 2.9.0.1, same error: 
scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.9.0.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
scalac *
HelloWorld.scala:4: error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: Constants.WORLD
  @myAnn(name = Constants.WORLD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug that only shows up when feeding the java source files into the scala compiler, see issue [SI-2764](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2764). The example works when compiling the java files first using `javac` and then pointing `scalac`'s classpath to the generated classfiles.

Comment: The bug now says it's been fixed in Scala 2.10.